# Problems with Stylesheet/CSS/link error

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Attempting an assignment, and managed the initial step, but when I go into the index.html on my browser I see weird characters in the box.

[inspector view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPtum.png) vs [text editor view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAdnw.png)

Then I proceeded to link CSS into the .html file and it appeared exactly as it did in the inspector view image. (see below for css code and html code with link)

I tried editting the files, removing cache from my browser and saw a suggestion to check on inspector and remove the stylesheet. But no luck, I have no idea what to do at this point.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0c93b0;
}
#profile_screen {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100;
}
#information_holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #666666;
}
#my_name {
  color: white;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#date_of_birth {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#current_age,
#current_weight {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#main_navigation_holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.main_button {
  width: 50% height: 100% -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 85px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#settings_page_button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(‘../images/currentmedications@2x.png’);
}
#health_history_button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url(‘../images/medicalhistory@2x.png’);
}
#add_item_screen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype>

<html>


<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index_files/index.css">
</head>


<body>

  <div id=“profile_screen” class=“screen”></div>
  <div id=“information_holder”>
    <h1 id=“my_name”> John Doe</h1>
    <h2 id=“date_of_birth”>02/28/2015</h2>
    <h3 id=“current_age”>01 yrs old </h3>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id=“add_item_screen” class=“screen”></div>

  <div id=“list_of_history_screen” class=“screen”></div>

  <div id=“settings_screen” class=“screen”></div>

  <div id=“main_navigation_holder”>
    <input type=“button” id=“settings_page_button” value="Settings" />
    <input type=“button” id=“health_history_button” value="Health History" />
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `"` instead of `“` and 
Put this code in the `head` and try again ?

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Your code should be like this

```html
<div id="profile_screen" class="screen"></div>
<div id="information_holder">
  <h1 id="my_name"> John Doe</h1>
  <h2 id="date_of_birth">02/28/2015</h2>
  <h3 id="current_age">01 yrs old </h3>
</div>

<div id="add_item_screen" class="screen"></div>

<div id="list_of_history_screen" class="screen"></div>

<div id="settings_screen" class="screen"></div>

<div id="main_navigation_holder">
  <input type="button" id="settings_page_button" value="Settings" />
  <input type="button" id="health_history_button" value="Health History" />
</div>
```

Comment: Tried it out, looks better in regards with no weird characters, however in the second box it only displays "History" and not the full text "Health History"[revised code](http://i.imgur.com/dLm9NRZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just use normal quote characters " " instead of “ ” in your html file.

Check it out [here](http://yt5ytt.ddns.net/test_answer)

Comment: Nevermind, I restarted and checked all the " Characters, now its good.